# AWS cli configure fails to set profile although the 'config' and 'credentials' files are generated at ~/home/.aws

Tags: aws-cli, ubuntu-22.04

I have a serious problem configuring an AWS cli profile. I run on Ubuntu 22.04. I open a terminal and press `aws configure --profile bright_eu`. I insert the required keys and region and press 'enter'. The "config" and "credentials" files are generated correctly at the default directory ~/.aws. However, it seems that the profile is not set when I try to list it using `aws configure list` everything seems to be unset!

I checked with `env` command to see if any AWS environmental variables are there but nothing comes up. The same when I try with `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

I have looked everywhere but no one seems to have faced something similar, I don't find any solution... Can someone help? It seems that it does not locate the credentials!
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try `aws iam list-users --profile bright_eu`?

Comment: Yes, although I follow the configuring profile process, it seems that it fails without generating an error. I uninstalled cli and installed it back, configured it again, got the files but when I ttype 'aws sts get-caller-identity' it gives "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure". I don't get it at all..

Answer (score 0):

This configures a profile named `bright_eu`:

```
aws configure --profile bright_eu
```

It **does not** set that as the current profile. It just configures the profile. The `aws configure` command is **only** for editing the files in `~/.aws/` **not** for setting your shell's current profile or environment variables.

To use a specific profile in your AWS commands, you have to add `--profile bright_eu` to each AWS CLI command, for example:

```
aws iam list-users --profile bright_eu
```

Or, as detailed in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html), set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable to specify the profile to use for all aws cli commands in the current shell:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=bright_eu

aws iam list-users
```